# Image uploading php error

Tags: php, mysqli

This is simple php script which check extension of image as jpeg to png and working fine.Problem is suppose someone rename any other file as .exe/.txt to jpeg,then it will accept file.So how can i limit that even on renaming if it is not image then return false.I can apply restriction like file size,etc but anybody can overrule it.I tried lot but none helped:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $errors     = array();
    $maxsize    = 2097152;
    $acceptable = array(
        'application/pdf',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/jpg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png'
    );

    if(($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0)) {
        $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';
    }

    if(!in_array($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'], $acceptable)) && (!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]))) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only PDF, JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted.';
    }

    if(count($errors) === 0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmpname'], '/store/to/location.file');
    } else {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<script>alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
        }

        die(); //Ensure no more processing is done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use finfo_file => see here http://php.net/manual/de/function.finfo-file.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
  $errors     = array();
  $maxsize    = 2097152;
  $acceptable = array(
    'application/pdf',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/jpg',
    'image/gif',
    'image/png'
  );
  // CHECK FILE_TYPE
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
  $type = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['uploaded_file']) ;
  // DEV-INFO
  echo $type; die;
  // ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getimagesize() function. It will determine the size of any GIF, JPG, PNG, XBM, or WBMP image file. if it is not a valid picture, getimagesize() will return FALSE